# Trying to validate docx file using OpenXml.WordProcessingDocument throws error if file has tables or images

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, openxml

I want to validate ".docx" file before I upload to server. For that I've used OpenXmlValidator.WordProcessingDocument. The following code works fine but fails for cases such as:

- Word file containing tables.
- Word file with images.
- Word file with.
  background colour.

Here is the code:

```
private static List<string> ValidateDocFile(IFormFile file)
    {
        List<string> message = new List<string>();
        var inputstream = file.OpenReadStream();
        var xmlDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(inputstream, false);

        int count = 0;
        try
        {
            OpenXmlValidator validator = new OpenXmlValidator();
            foreach (ValidationErrorInfo error in validator.Validate(xmlDoc))
            {
                count++;
                message.Add("Description: " + error.Description);
            }
            xmlDoc.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            message.Add(ex.Message);
        }
        return message;
    }
```

Here is the response I've received:

- ```
    message Count = 6   System.Collections.Generic.List<string>
    [0] "Description: The 'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main:firstRow' attribute is not declared."   string
    [1] "Description: The 'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main:lastRow' attribute is not declared."    string
    [2] "Description: The 'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main:firstColumn' attribute is not declared."    string
    [3] "Description: The 'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main:lastColumn' attribute is not declared." string
    [4] "Description: The 'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main:noHBand' attribute is not declared."    string
    [5] "Description: The 'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main:noVBand' attribute is not declared."    string
  ```

[Here's the Quick-Watch of the variable "message"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJRAj.png)

This response was for the word file containing Table.
Similar issues come for word file with image and background colour.

Any fix for this, tried looking on OpenXmldevelopers.org but no result.

Also Word version cannot be specified as the end-user could be using any version. The above result was obtained for Word v2016 and v2019.

Following is the content of the file:
[image: The word file which threw above error]

Comment: im guessing the validation is just out of date. they don't appear to be hard errors.

Comment: Pardon me @DanielA.White, I didn't understand Validation out-of-date as in? Validation is necessary before we upload file to blob and this issue is causing file-upload failure to server which is a big risk.

Comment: meaning that the tool may not fully support newer features that were added since it was written

Comment: The following may be useful: https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK/issues